# Using Titanium MapView without using current location - iOS

Tags: ios, location, titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app with Titanium 2.1.4 SDK. I am displaying a couple of annotations on a MapView which is centered at a location sent by the server. I do not want to know user's location. But, when the window with MapView opens, iPhone shows a dialog saying that the app wants to know the user location, even after adding **userLocation:false** parameter to Mapview.

How can I disable that popup dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to get rid of this popup. its uses native core functionality and it will appear as soon as you open the map ..